# The exception message is 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: propertyResourceType'

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-4.1, wcf-data-services

just installed WCF CTP2 mar2011 and trying to access web service through browser.  (http://localhost:99/Services/MyDataService.svc/)
I get this exception:

```
**The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: propertyResourceType'. See server logs for more details.** The exception stack trace is:
at System.Data.Services.Providers.ResourceProperty..ctor(String name, ResourcePropertyKind kind, ResourceType propertyResourceType)
at System.Data.Services.Providers.ObjectContextServiceProvider.PopulateMemberMetadata(ResourceType resourceType, IProviderMetadata workspace, IDictionary`2 knownTypes, PrimitiveResourceTypeMap primitiveResourceTypeMap)
at System.Data.Services.Providers.ObjectContextServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata(IDictionary`2 knownTypes, IDictionary`2 childTypes, IDictionary`2 entitySets)
at System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.LoadMetadata()
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider()
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream messageBody)
at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Any help?

Update.Found out that problem is related with this property

```
 [Required]
    public byte TypeId { get; set; }

    public ContactInfoType Type
    {
        get
        {
            return (ContactInfoType)TypeId;
        }
        set
        {
            TypeId = (byte)value;
        }
    }
```

Interresting thing is that everything is ok in WCF4. But it throws an exeption in WCF CTP2march.
ContactInfoType - is an enum.

[IgnoreProperties("Type")] makes no effect.

Update2. After investigating a problem found out that exception thrown in the setter part of the property.

```
  public ContactInfoType Type
    {
        set
        {
            TypeId = (byte)value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I lost my crystal ball. Could you please post some code? The only thing I'm able to tell you is that you passed `null` as `propertyResourceType` to a `ResourceProperty` constructor while you shouldn't.

Comment: sorry for that. Added web service body. And I'v just trying to access this web service by opening it in browser.

Answer (score 3):

I received the same error in a .NET 4.5 WCF Data Services service (presumably using WCF Data Services 5.0).  After upgrading to WCF Data Services 5.2.0 (via NuGet) I received more helpful error messages that pointed me to the problem property, which was an `enum` typed property, same as above.

Wow, enums are still not supported in WCF Data Services 5.2.0 - it's the most voted for feature here: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72027-wcf-data-services-feature-suggestions (vote if you care about it!)

There are currently two options for working around this - one is to expose a scalar property and use the `[NotMapped]` attribute on the enum property, and back them with the same single value.  The other option is to create an "enum-like" entity class that replaces the enum type, which has the added benefit that the enum values are stored in the DB.  Here's an example:

```
public class Priority
{
    public Priority()
    {}

    protected Priority(short id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static readonly Priority Unknown = new Priority(0, "Unknown");
    public static readonly Priority Optional = new Priority(1, "Optional");
    public static readonly Priority Low = new Priority(2, "Low");
    public static readonly Priority Normal = new Priority(3, "Normal");
    public static readonly Priority High = new Priority(4, "High");
    public static readonly Priority Critical = new Priority(5, "Critical");
    public static readonly Priority Blocking = new Priority(6, "Blocking");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a wild guess, but could it be [this issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/511877/ado-net-data-service-fails-when-data-model-contains-property-of-type-datetimeoffset):

> When an Entity Data Model contains an entity type that has a property
>   of type DateTimeOffset, an ADO.NET Data Service throws an unhandled
>   ArgumentNullException. If you change the property type to DateTime,
>   the exception goes away.

Comment: Everything is fine if I make reference to the WCF4. Error appears then I use WCF4 CTP2 march2011